# Reactive pipeline using Mutiny operators

Tags: java, reactive-programming, quarkus, quarkus-panache, mutiny

I am working on a **reactive quarkus** backend service which does the following.

1. Fetch a list of records from backend using **Hibernate Reactive Panache** interacting with postgres
2. Using record's identifier, fetch data from another remote service.

I am using **Mutiny** to perform the reactive pipelining. **Remote service and database integrations are all individually working fine** in a non-blocking way. I just need help with writing a pipeline linking those.
For eg: Something like below

```java
    public Uni<List<Post>> findAllBooks() {
        return Book.listAll()             // Entity returns Uni<List<Book>> succesfully.
                    .map(Collection::stream)
                    .flatMap(book -> postApiClient.getPost(book.getId())  // Reactive postApiClient returns Uni<Post> successfully.
                    .collect(toList());
```

I am stuck processing a Uni wrapping a List and then trying to process individual items in that list. Either Uni<List> or Multi would just work fine for me. I just want it to non-blocking throughout.

Comment: A `Uni` of a `List` has a weird semantics. I think it would make more sense if the HTTP `POST` returns a `Multi<Book>`.

Comment: `PanacheEntityBase` returns `Uni<List<T>` for `listAll` operation.

Comment: It's not weird, it's on purpose. If you have the content in memory, no need to create a Multi. `listAll()` retrieves the list in memory, so it returns a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to achieve the objective by writing the following pipeline.

1. Transform the List<Uni> objects returned by PancheEntity into Multi using the list as iterable.
2. For each item on the Multi, Invoke the non-blocking remote service.

I wasn't worried about order hence used `transformToUniAndMerge`. For those who needs to maintain order of data as is in the original list use `transformToUniAndConcatenate`

```java
public Multi<String> hello() {
    return Uni.createFrom().item(List.of("hello", "Django", "Hola"))  // Creating a list of Uni as would be returned by PanacheEntity
        .onItem().transformToMulti(x -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(x))  // Transform into Multi by passing the iterable
        .onItem().transformToUniAndMerge(this::mockRemoteService);  // Invoke the non-blocking remote service which returns Uni
}

private Uni<String> mockRemoteService(String item) {
    return Uni.createFrom().item((item + " mutiny").toUpperCase());
}
```